# I need Strophe jingle plugin Documentation or any tutorial/example

Tags: xmpp, javascript, openfire, strophe, libjingle

I have created the browser based chat client which uses strophe JavaScript lib to connect to openfire server.
Now i need support for VOIP and video stream feature in that application.

I have checked the strophe website for specific plugin for above features, they have provided [jingle plugin/extension](https://github.com/mweibel/strophejs-plugins/tree/jingle/jingle) but doesn't have any documentation or examples.

I have tried to build the library as per specification provided on [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0166.html) , but its taking much time.

So if some one have any documentation or working example then it will help me to develop the feature.
Or any other extension which is created on the top of strophe which provide the jingle support it will be helpful.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or direction.

Regards,
Kamlesh

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar situation. I've searched over the internet and I found strophe.jingle. I haven't tested it yet but it seems simple and nice. It uses WebRTC protocol for video and audio support. https://github.com/ESTOS/strophe.jingle